# remove special characters when getting the value from the file

Tags: shell

When creating directory dynamically the value is getting created with additional junk character as **?**

```
inputfile.txt
a=B
f=G
M=N
o=Z
..
..
```

Below are the steps i follow to create the directory.

1. Need to get the value of M and create a directory in /user/home/abc/test/

   Commands I tried :
   var1=`cat input_file.txt | grep M | cut -d "=" -f2`
   mkdir -p /user/home/abc/test/${var1}

It creates the directory but output is having garbage value like below

```
Command :
ls -ltr /user/home/abc/test/

Output : 
N?

Expected Output : 
N
```

Can you kindly suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: `inputfile.txt` probably has DOS line endings (CR/LF); convert it to Unix line endings (LF only). The `?` is the carriage return from the DOS pair.

Comment: @user148267 : Or, more general (than the suggestion by chepner), look at your input file with, i.e., `xxd`, to see what bytes are there before the line feed.

Comment: Repair the input file with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//'`